# I want append the th before the data from loop

Tags: jquery, html

```
<table id="tablename" class="ui table small segment" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tablename-tbody">
            <tr><td style="text-align: center;" colspan="3"><div class="ui active inline loader"></div></td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

So this is my table

This jquery below is the problem I always see this at bottom

```
$('#tablename').append('<th>th1</th><th>th2</th><th>th3</i></th>');
```

the the data from loop

```
$('#tablename tr').html( data ); <-- contains <tr><td>.....</td></tr> from loop
```

Comment: What isn't working, descripe your problems, what is your question?

Comment: $('#tablename').append('<th>th1</th><th>th2</th><th>th3</i></th>');  this one I always see this at the bottom of the data

Comment: this is a very low quality question what exactly is your problem, try to be clear

Comment: sorry I'm newbie here sorry

Comment: @superdb You should check out the [ask] page. Putting more work into a question will often get you more attention and better answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you'd want to put your headings in the `thead` element:

```
$('#tablename thead').html('<tr><th>th1</th><th>th2</th><th>th3</i></th></tr>');
```

... and the data in the `tbody` element:

```
$('#tablename tbody').html( data );
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/pLbd1t0r/1/)

Otherwise, the `append()` method places content at the end of an element. You could certainly use `prepend()`.

Comment: +1 wanted to write that too, but made the fiddle...

Comment: 5 mins Ill check you.

Comment: Michael, your fiddle resulted in invalid HTML structure. (The `th` elements were outside the table rows.) I've updated it. Thanks.